# Blazor WASM - Controller not found when making a PostAsJsonAsync Request

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

I am building a WASM app for the first time, and have been following tutorials.

The Solution I have is composed of 3 projects created by the wizard (Client, Server and Shared).

I am having trouble when making the following request from the index page:

```
var msg = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<u001_000_001>("api/u001_000_001", userRec);

If (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode) ClearUserScr();
```

In the Server project, I have a Controllers folder with a controller named u001-000-001Controller (although the class name in the file is u001_000_001Controller). The relevant lines of code from the controller class are as follows:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class u001_000_001Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<u001_000_001> Post([FromBody] u001_000_001 create)
    {
        EntityEntry<u001_000_001> user = await db.u001_000_001.AddAsync(create);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return user.Entity;
    }
}
```

The HttpClient is registered using the builder.HostEnvironment.baseAddress as the Uri in the Client Program.cs file.

The Shared folder contains the handler called u001-000-001 (class name u001_000_001).

I have tried all the different combinations I can think of in terms of changing the names in the actual call, and nothing works. I keep getting the same "not found - HTTP 400' error.

I would sincerely appreciate help from experienced eyes to see if there is a simple mistake I'm making or if there's something more serious I'm missing. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Add `api/` as in `PostAsJsonAsync<u001_000_001>("api/u001_000_001", userRec);`

Comment: You need to inherit a controller base class. `public class u001_000_001Controller : ControllerBase`

Comment: Thank you very much for those suggestions Brian and Henk. I have now tried both of these and the same error persists. Is it possible this error is being generated due to a system/browser issue, or perhaps a VS2022 issue? I only ask because I have tried these suggestions and many other permutations throughout many tutorials and am not able to resolve this HTTP 400 error in Firefox Debugger console. Many thanks again for your time on this.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: The suggestions made by Henk and Brian above have now been edited into the original post, but I want to highlight for ethical reasons that these additions were made AFTER their input, with thanks again to both contributors for their feedback.

Comment: what is the base address of this blazor HTTP client?

Comment: Hi Mohammed, the base address is as follows: BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)

Comment: @Henk if you have a chance at some stage, could I please request any further insights you might have regarding this issue, as you obviously seem to have a lot of experience. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just Post here, I'll read most of the [blazor] questions.

Comment: In this case I suggest creating a [mre].   Post all changes made from the starter template app.

Comment: @Henk thank you very much for the advice. I will get to work creating the minimal reproducible example and then post all of the code as an edit to this original question (I assume this would be preferable than creating a new question). Cheers.

Comment: @Henk As per your previous recommendation, I tried creating the minimal version and the code in the original question is unchanged. I have since also tried to use a version of the controller and handler that use names without the underscores but this made no difference. I am currently still getting the http/1.1 400 Bad Request error. Is it possible the problem relates to the SQL Server settings (e.g. security settings) rather than the Blazor WASM project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many hours of research later, the error was found to be in the fields being fed initially into the handler, rather than anything happening with the actual HttpClient request or the controller.

Although I found that the Http/1.1 400 Bad request error could be generated by a range of issues, I would highly recommend reviewing the structure of the data being input as a first step, since this was overlooked in my case.

Clarification of Issue and Solution:
I have a process for creating new user logins, and the goal of the HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync request was to send new account details to the database. However one of the fields in the user record is a PIN number, and as this is not chosen by the new user in the first registration step, it was left as null in the code.

Keeping it null was fine for the code, but the Controller expects data to be input for all fields, and will not accept PostAsJsonAsync calls where any of the fields are left null.

The solution in my case was to set a temporary value, and then make the PostAsJsonAsync request with all of the fields filled and sent through the request.

I wish to thank the professionals who commented with potential solutions, as they helped to improve my code.

Comment: Answers should have a clear solution for the sake of future people searching similar topics or questions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @KentWong Thank you for highlighting the need for clarification. I have added the Clarification of Issue and Solution section to give an overview of the issue, and I hope that helps. Cheers.